# How to generate count query with criteria api

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to count the results returned by queries that are constructed with the criteria api.
I don't want to rewrite any of these queries. I tried

```
(Integer)criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
```

which may work but depending on the joins and restrictions Hibernate 3.2.4 will generate

> invalid sql (DB2: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.co: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-119,
>   SQLSTATE=42803, which means "A COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IN A HAVING CLAUSE
>   IS NOT VALID"). Example below...

If the original sql is

```
select * from ... where ... order by ...
```

then the count projection basically just replaces the * with `count(*)` which gives something like

```
select count(*) as y0_ from ... where ... order by ...
```

which may throw an error. This could be easily corrected by wrapping the original SQL and prepending `select count(*)`:

```
select count(*) from (select * from ... where ... order by ...);
```

How could this be achieved or what else would you suggest?

---

Here an example of the invalid sql:

```
select count(*) as y0_
from UZI.Ereignis this_
left outer join UZI.Zaehlerzustand zaehlerzus1_ on this_.zustandHz_id=zaehlerzus1_.id
left outer join UZI.Mandant mandantali3_ on zaehlerzus1_.mandant_id=mandantali3_.id
left outer join UZI.Zaehlerzustand zaehlerzus2_ on this_.zustandNz_id=zaehlerzus2_.id
left outer join UZI.Mandant mandantali4_ on zaehlerzus2_.mandant_id=mandantali4_.id
where (zaehlerzus1_.zaehlernummer like ? or zaehlerzus2_.zaehlernummer like ?)
and (mandantali3_.id=? or mandantali4_.id=?)
order by this_.id desc
```

Comment: I just found out that the order-by-clause is the troublemaker. If I setup the criteria without 

    criteria.addOrder(..);

then the count will work.

Comment: Have a look at this, discusses the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370221/remove-dynamically-an-ordering-to-the-result-set-in-org-hibernate-criteria

Comment: Thanks. Actually I wanted hibernate to create something like  "select count(*) from (select * ...)", but because I am able to reconstruct the criteria without the order by clause, this will be my workaround.