# Hibernate: Projections.rowCount() causing problems in MS SQL when criteria has Order by clause. Works fine in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, hibernate-criteria

I have recently moved my DB from Oracle to SQL Server. My Application uses hibernate v5.x.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ABC.class);

setResultPaging(criteria, 1, 100);

//Add all criteria restrictions
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ABCId", ABCSearch.getId());
...
...
...
//All restrictions added. Now add Order by.

criteria.addOrder(Property.forName("endDate").desc());
criteria.addOrder(Property.forName("startDate").asc());
criteria.addOrder(Property.forName("ABCId").asc());

List<ABC> ABCList = criteria.list();

if (ABCList.size() > 0) {
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.rowCount()));
setResultPaging(criteria, 0, 1);
searchResult.setTotalResults(CountTranslate.translateCount(criteria.list())); <-- Error happens here.
}
```

//CountTranslate.translateCount() typecasts criteria.list into Integer

While performing the criteria.list() within the 2nd time, it gives me the error as below,

```
Column "ABC.END_DATE" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
2023-07-16 08:49:38,051 WARN  \[services-pool housekeeper\] : services-pool - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1m20s409ms434µs600ns).
2023-07-16 08:49:41,474 ERROR \[RMI TCP Connection(14)-192.168.43.237\] : New DAOException -
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1922)
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:370)
```

The Hibernate Query appearing in the logs is below,

```
select count(*) as y0_ 
from ABC this_

inner join ABC_REQUEST abcreques1_ 
on this_.ABC_REQUEST_ID=abcreques1_.ABC_REQUEST_ID

where 
abcreques1_.FORM_TYPE=? and 
this_.ABC_STATUS=? and 
this_.ARCHIVED_FLAG=?

order by 
this_.END_DATE desc, 
this_.START_DATE asc, 
this_.ABC_ID asc 
offset 0 rows fetch next ? rows only
```

//ABC_REQUEST is an associated table.

This was working well in Oracle, but after moving to SQL Server, this errors out. I am unsure why HQL is building a query which is not recognized by SQL Server as legitimate...!!! Am I doing something wrong..??!!!

FYI, I am using the SQLServer2012Dialect

Comment: I've formatted the generated SQL for readability. FWIW the use of an `ORDER BY` and `OFFSET` in a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query is odd... I'm also unsure where those backslashes are coming from (as T-SQL doesn't use them for escaping identifiers or underscores...)

Comment: @Dai - I have edited the SQL query now...It was a little mislaigned earlier...

Comment: And yes, that query which hibernate generates is really odd...I tried to put it on SQL client...and it gives the same error...The error however looks legitimate from SQL Server point of view...but then the prime concern i have is...why is hibernate generating a bad HQL when it knows the dialect..!!??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, found a way out. Using CriteriaImpl, I was able to remove the Order By clause prior to the 2nd criteria.list() call. Took reference from here - [Remove dynamically an ordering to the result set in org.hibernate.Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370221/remove-dynamically-an-ordering-to-the-result-set-in-org-hibernate-criteria). My updated code looks like below,

Note: I still feel that this is a workaround to the problem. The count query produced by hibernate isn't going well with SQL Server but it did work well with Oracle using Oracle9dialect hibernate dialect. So, the hibernate dialect - SQLServer2012Dialect should ideally be able to handle this, and it shouldn't produce a bad HQL for Projections rowcount..!!!

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ABC.class);
    
setResultPaging(criteria, 1, 100);
    
//Add all criteria restrictions
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ABCId", ABCSearch.getId());
...
...
...
//All restrictions added. Now add Order by.
    
criteria.addOrder(Property.forName("endDate").desc());
criteria.addOrder(Property.forName("startDate").asc());
criteria.addOrder(Property.forName("ABCId").asc());
    
List<ABC> ABCList = criteria.list();
    
if (ABCList.size() > 0) { 
 
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.rowCount()));
setResultPaging(criteria, 0, 1);
//New code to remove the Order By Clauses from criteria
Iterator<CriteriaImpl.OrderEntry> orderIter 
 = ((CriteriaImpl)criteria).iterateOrderings();
 while (orderIter.hasNext()) {
   orderIter.next();
   orderIter.remove();
}
searchResult.setTotalResults(CountTranslate.translateCount(criteria.list())); 
//Now the criteria.list() translates to an HQL that no more throws the 'Invlaid in Order by clause' error. 
}
```